# Remove first element of JSON object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, fetch

I'm struggling to find a way to cut down this JSON array so I can use the values remaining. Below is what's returned to me from the API I'm fetching and I'm looking to remove the excess so I just have an array with the LGA results. Really unsure where to even start.

```
{
  "query": {
    "offence": "Dangerous Operation of a Vehicle",
    "area": "",
    "age": "",
    "year": "",
    "gender": ""
  },
  "result": [
    {
      "LGA": "Aurukun Shire Council",
      "total": 156,
      "lat": -13.354875,
      "lng": 141.729058
    },
    {
      "LGA": "Balonne Shire Council",
      "total": 99,
      "lat": -28.464607,
      "lng": 148.189292
    },
    {
      "LGA": "Yarrabah Shire Council",
      "total": 28,
      "lat": -16.910135,
      "lng": 145.868659
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Question is not clear. What is the expected output?

Comment: Please provive a really question => https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please remove the extra data and only keep the data required to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

`You can try:`

```
response.data.result = response.data.result.slice(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array​.prototype​.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to transform your result:

```
const response = getYourJsonFromAPI()
response.result.map(result => result.LGA)
```

which returns:

```
["Aurukun Shire Council", "Balonne Shire Council", "Yarrabah Shire Council"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you get the response from API, but you can try:

```
console.log(response.data.result);
```

Answer (score 0):

for example, if you want only LGA values, you could use something like that:

```
let parsedJson = JSON.parse(json);                //parse json to object
let onlyLGAValues = {};                           //create a new dictionary

parsedJson.result.forEach(function(key, index){   //for each result
    onlyLGAValues[index] = key.LGA;               //push the LGA value in the new dictionary
}); 

console.log(onlyLGAValues);
```

expected output:

```
{0: "Aurukun Shire Council", 1: "Balonne Shire Council", ... 77: "Yarrabah Shire Council"}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your question correctly, you want to get a `string` array containing the `LGA` properties:

```
const data = {
  query: {
    offence: "Dangerous Operation of a Vehicle",
    area: "",
    age: "",
    year: "",
    gender: ""
  },
  result: [{}, {}] // your current large array
};

const lgaArray = data.result.map(({ LGA }) => ({ LGA }));

console.table(lgaArray);
```

A screenshot to give a visual aid:

[image: lga map array]